# how to match multiple patterns in string?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How do i match multiple patterns and fetch the value corresponding to that pattern.

I have a table like this :

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
table_1 <- data.table(names = c('bluecdsd','red321','yellowVsds523','423_black','ewrwblack'),
                      value = runif(5))
```

And the pattern table like this:

```
table_2 <- data.table(category = c('black','blue','red','white'),
                      size = c('small','little','large','huge'))
```

What I want the result:

```
           names     value   size
1:      bluecdsd 0.5995658 little
2:        red321 0.4935413  large
3: yellowVsds523 0.1862176     NA
4:     423_black 0.8273733  small
5:     ewrwblack 0.6684667  small
```

I know I should use regexpr, but don't know how to match multiple patterns, Any help pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep `category` of table2 with `names` of table1 and get the values of `names` of table1 and assign it to table2. Once we have `names` in both tables, we can use `join` approach based `on = .(names)` and bind the `size` from table2 to table1.

```
  library(data.table)      
  table_2 <- table_2[, .(names = grep( unique(category), table_1[, names], value =  TRUE  ), size = size ),
                     by = category ]
  table_2 <- table_2[!is.na(names), ]

  table_1[table_2, `:=` ( size = i.size), on = c('names')]
  table_1
  #            names     value   size
  # 1:      bluecdsd 0.2655087 little
  # 2:        red321 0.3721239  large
  # 3: yellowVsds523 0.5728534     NA
  # 4:     423_black 0.9082078  small
  # 5:     ewrwblack 0.2016819  small
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
table_1 <- data.table(names = c('bluecdsd','red321','yellowVsds523','423_black','ewrwblack'),
                        value = runif(5))

table_2 <- data.table(category = c('black','blue','red','white'),
                        size = c('small','little','large','huge'))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can `extract` the substring and do a `match`

```
library(stringr)
table_1[, size := table_2$size[match(str_extract(names, 
            paste(table_2$category, collapse="|")), table_2$category)]]
table_1
#          names     value   size
#1:      bluecdsd 0.2655087 little
#2:        red321 0.3721239  large
#3: yellowVsds523 0.5728534     NA
#4:     423_black 0.9082078  small
#5:     ewrwblack 0.2016819  small
```